# Laravel Error when creating composite foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, composite-primary-key

I need to build a table named 'slides' that contains two columns named 'id' and 'work_id'. The ID is not an AUTO_INCREMENT integer because I need to keep the numbers as the index inside a slideshow.

This is the error that is displayed when running 'php artisan migrate':
[image: Error]

And this is my code:

```
Schema::create('slides', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id');
    $table->integer('work_id');

    $table->primary(['id', 'work_id']);
    $table->foreign('work_id')->references('id')->on('works');
});
```

This is the structure of my 'works' table:
[image: Works Table]

And this is the structure of the 'slides' table that is generated despite the error occurring:
[image: Slides Table]

I don't understand the error message because I'm not very fluent with SQL so could someone tell me what's wrong with the code that makes it output this error? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the whole code for migration? I think it's not

Comment: Yes, this is the entire code for the migration I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how, if at all, Eloquent handles composite keys.  That said, your error message is coming out of MySQL.  The cryptic error 150 usually has something to do with an ill formed foreign key constraint.

If your case above, it looks like the `work_id` foreign key in `slides` is not the same type as the `id` you're trying to match it with.  While both columns are `int`s, one is `int(10)`, the other is `int(11)`.  It also appears one is `UNSIGNED` and the other is signed.

If you can fiddle with your migrations so both columns are identical, you should be able to solve this specific foreign key problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly the problem. I'd forgotten that a foreign key must have the same data type as it's primary counterpart. Works perfectly after adding '->unsigned()' on to the ID column in my 'works' table and the ID and Work_ID columns in my 'slides' table.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind that could case problem is your primary key.

You should try to change:

```
$table->primary(['id', 'work_id']);
```

into

```
$table->primary('id');
```

to check if it's working now

Comment: After changing that code, the error still occurs although it did change slightly. What I'm wondering now is if I even need to specify work_id as a foreign key due to a composite key being a primary key and foreign key by default. This is the new error: http://i.gyazo.com/25fa4478bf1de94a76fe0d57bb7e2e78.png

Comment: @LiamPotter Are you sure this table doesn't exist already in your database? You should check it in phpmyadmin for example

Comment: It doesn't exist before I run the migration but it does afterwards despite the error occurring. However, every time the migration fails I drop the created table.